# i keep glitching in overwatch ps4 please help

Tags: overwatch

I have recently experienced some glitching in overwatch ps4.  Is this just my controler or are other people experiencing this?  By glitching I mean i start to move without touching anything thing, and there were no Zayras in the game.

Comment: Kind of sounds like lag to me...

Comment: What is your internet connection speed? ISP? Wired or wireless?

Comment: Would need a lot more details to make a definitive diagnosis, but yeah, that sounds like lag.

Comment: its not my internet. this was a speed test taken while overwatch was running http://www.speedtest.net/result/5735176167.png

Comment: i mean like my hero starts to move uncontrollably for a little bit

Comment: Sounds like a busted controller to me.

Answer (score 2):

IT sounds like a bad connection or lag

are you moving back and forth like sliding along the ground?

if so thats lag

Comment: my hero starts to walk not slide